# Python datetime isocalendar giving wrong tuple

Tags: python, datetime, iso

Here is my python code

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1)
print(a.isocalendar())
```

and the output is

```
(2011, 52, 7)
```

The format for the output is a tuple containing year, weeknumber and weekday in respective order for the given date instance.

Why is this so? Shouldn't it be `(2012, 1, 1)`, if not how can I convert it to an absolute weeknumber?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want a North American week number, not an ISO week number.

```
>>> a = datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1)
>>> a.strftime("%Y %U")
'2012 01'
```

Comment: If I type `a = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1) a.strftime("%Y %U")`It gives output as `2021 00`

Comment: @AkshatZala Attaching a comment to a 2-year old answer is unlikely to get a helpful response. Ask your own question, that describes not only what the `%U` directive does that you do not expect, but also what you *do* expect. That isn't obvious to everyone, however obvious it might be to you. The reason you get the week number zero for 1-Jan-2021 is because in that system week 1 is the one that begins with the first Sunday of the year (which was 3-Jan-2021), and all days prior to the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0 (which you can choose to regard as week 53 of the previous year).

Answer (score 5):

As per the [documentation of `isocalendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar):

> Return a 3-tuple, (ISO year, ISO week number, ISO weekday).
>
> The ISO calendar is a widely used variant of the Gregorian calendar. See [https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/calendar/isocalendar.htm](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/%7Egent0113/calendar/isocalendar.htm) for a good explanation.
>
> The ISO year consists of 52 or 53 full weeks, and where a week starts on a Monday and ends on a Sunday. **The first week of an ISO year is the first (Gregorian) calendar week of a year containing a Thursday.** This is called week number 1, and the ISO year of that Thursday is the same as its Gregorian year.
>
> For example, 2004 begins on a Thursday, so the first week of ISO year 2004 begins on Monday, 29 Dec 2003 and ends on Sunday, 4 Jan 2004, so that date(2003, 12, 29).isocalendar() == (2004, 1, 1) and date(2004, 1, 4).isocalendar() == (2004, 1, 7).

In your case, Jan 1 2012 is a Sunday, so according to the ISO calendar rules the first week of 2012 is Jan 2 -- Jan 8 (because the first Thursday is Jan 5), and Jan 1 belongs to the last week of 2011.